# How to make . match all in apache configuration?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

Inside httpd.conf:

```
 rewriterule  ^questions/([0-9]+).*  ...
```

It matches `/questions/1674/<textarea>`,but not `/questions/1674/<textarea><%2Ftextarea>`

Comment: Are you rebuilding ServerFault? :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you have an encoded forward slash in the URI, Apache returns an immediete 404. The error log will state:

**[info] [client 1.2.3.4] found %2f (encoded '/') in URI (decoded='/question/1/'), returning 404**

To work around this, add to your httpd.conf root or `<VirtualHost>` section the following directive:

`AllowEncodedSlashes On`

And then your rewrite will work. Information from the Apache manual:

> The AllowEncodedSlashes directive
>   allows URLs which contain encoded path
>   separators (%2F for / and additionally
>   %5C for \ on according systems) to be
>   used. Normally such URLs are refused
>   with a 404 (Not found) error.

For more information, see:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes

http://blog.dynom.nl/archives/Apaches-fail-with-encoded-slashes_20090625_40.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need the No Escape [NE] flag on the rule? Search for noescape in [this page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: This flag deals with the output of rewrite,but my problem seems to be the input of the rewrite.